# What is the purpose of "C:\swapfile.sys" in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, pagefile

On Windows 8 there are the following two files in C:\

1. pagefile.sys - no surprise. It is as big as I configured as my page file size
2. swapfile.sys - it is 256MB in size

What is the purpose of this additional `swapfile.sys` file?

I'm looking for an authoritative answer on this. There is already enough speculation about this on the web.

Comment: The answers [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/W8ITProPreRel/thread/35351697-a1fc-4c39-9fc6-56edfe4241c9) seem fairly authoritative, naming suspend/resume of Metro apps as one main use for swapfile.sys.

Comment: @Indrek yes. I was hoping for a little more detail. Why *two* files? The existing answers are quite thin on detail.

Comment: Windows 8, oddly enough, supports both swapping and paging at the same time. The pagefile backs overcommitted physical memory and holds objects that haven't *been* accessed in a very long period of time. The swapfile holds things actively ejected from memory because they won't *be* accessed for awhile. Paging is more effective on high-performance desktops. Swapping is more effective on low-performance tablets and phones. If one file was used, it would get heavily fragmented because of the mix of small, fixed-size pages for paging and large chunks for swapping.

Comment: There needs to be two files because too many programs assume the pagefile will be used ONLY for paging, rather than paging *plus*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Several of the links off the posted answers end up linking to it, but http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2012/10/28/windows-8-windows-server-2012-the-new-swap-file.aspx

seems to be a more definitive answer:

> You may ask, “Why do we need another virtual page file?”  Well, with
>   the introduction of the Modern App, we needed a way to manage their
>   memory outside of the traditional Virtual Memory/Pagefile method. 
>   With that, the “%SystemDrive%\swapfile.sys” was born.
>
> Windows 8 can efficiently write the whole (private) working set of a
>   suspended Modern app to disk in order to gain additional memory when
>   the system detects pressure.  This process is analogous to hibernating
>   a specific app, and then resuming it when the user switches back to
>   the app.  In this case, Windows 8 takes advantage of the
>   suspend/resume mechanism of Modern apps to empty or re-populate an
>   app’s working set.

Answer (score 40):

From a Microsoft staff member at [Technet forums](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/W8ITProPreRel/thread/35351697-a1fc-4c39-9fc6-56edfe4241c9).

> This is a special type of pagefile used internally by the system to make certain types of paging operations more efficient. It is not related to the automatic dump setting.

> Suspend/resume of Metro-style apps is one scenario, there could be others in the future.

Answer (score 4):

While I'm not exactly sure what the purpose of it is, it looks like it is used to store/cache content that's currently in use.

If you're curious to see what's inside, you can [acquire locked files](http://blog.opensecurityresearch.com/2011/10/how-to-acquire-locked-files-from.html) like **swapfile.sys** or **pagefile.sys** from a running Windows system using [`FGET`](http://opensecurityresearch.com/files/FGET.zip) (Forensic Get by HBGary).

Run the the following command (as Administrator):

```
FGET -extract %systemdrive%\swapfile.sys OUTPUT_PATH
```

After which you can perform a string analysis using [`Strings`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439.aspx). Within **swapfile.sys** on my system, among other things I found:

> my email address, several emails and email addresses, environment
>   variables, partial content from web pages I visited, mimetype strings, user agent strings, XML files,
>   URLs, IP addresses, usernames, library function names, application
>   preferences, path strings, etc.

I also tried [carving the file](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/File_Carving) to look for common image formats and found several JPEGs and PNGs comprising of application icons, webpage resources, several profile pictures, image resources from Metro apps, etc.

---

If `FGET` doesn't work for you, try using [`ifind`](http://www.sleuthkit.org/sleuthkit/man/ifind.html) and [`icat`](http://www.sleuthkit.org/sleuthkit/man/icat.html) from [The Sleuth Kit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sleuthkit/).
You can find the MFT entry number for **swapfile.sys** using `ifind` as follows:

```
ifind -n /swapfile.sys \\.\%systemdrive%
```

Once you have the inode number, you can retrieve the file using `icat` as follows:

```
icat \\.\%systemdrive% INODE_NUMBER > OUTPUT_PATH
```

For example:

```
C:\>ifind -n /swapfile.sys \\.\%systemdrive%
1988

C:\>icat \\.\%systemdrive% 1988 > %systemdrive%\swapfile.dmp
```

**NOTE:** You need to run both commands from an elevated command prompt (i.e. run `cmd` as Administrator)

Comment: the tool crashes when I tried to run the command

Comment: @magicandre1981 You must run it as administrator. I forgot to mention that

Comment: I already did this.

Comment: @magicandre1981 What version of Windows are you running? Also, if FGET doesn't work for you, there are other ways to retrieve the swap file from a running system. Check the first link in my answer for some alternatives.

Comment: I use the original Windows 8 (64Bit). I get c0000417 (STATUS_INVALID_CRUNTIME_PARAMETER) as error code

Comment: @magicandre1981 I tested it on Windows 8.1 64-bit and it had no problems getting the swap file. Did you try using any of the other tools?

Comment: which other tool? I tried the posted FGET command

Comment: @magicandre1981 The other tools are mentioned in the first link I posted in my answer. They're [mentioned here](http://blog.opensecurityresearch.com/2011/10/how-to-acquire-locked-files-from.html). ntfscopy by TZWorks and icat and ifind from The Sleuth Kit. I'll update my answer shortly.

Comment: That link to FGET is dead.