# How to limit (not Disable) Swapfile.sys size?

Tags: windows-8, swap-file

How can I limit the size of **c:\swapfile.sys**?

I would expect **wmic swapfileset** to work, but it doesn't exist:

```
wmic swapfileset where name="c:\\swapfile.sys" set initialsize=1000,maximumsize=1000
swapfileset - Alias not found.
```

**If I can't limit it I'll disable it**

if I can't limit its size I'll probably disable it as described in https://superuser.com/a/512209/128465

**It's killing my SSD**

The Photos app uses 4GB memory:

```
wmic process get CreationDate,Name,PageFileUsage,PeakPageFileUsage | grep PhotosApp
20150129004217.258444+060  PhotosApp.exe                    2659428        4289992
```

Windows moves this to swapfile.sys when the app isn't used for a while.  It bothers me that Windows is frequently writing 4GB to my SSD, because it cant handle more than 100TB writes

```
dir /ah %systemdrive%\swapfile.sys | tail -3 | head -1
2015-01-29  14:59     3 103 784 960 swapfile.sys
```

**My speccy output:**

```
Operating System
    Windows 8.1 Enterprise 64-bit
CPU
    Intel Core i7 3770K @ 3.50GHz   37 °C
    Ivy Bridge 22nm Technology
RAM
    32,0GB Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 668MHz (9-9-9-24)
Motherboard
    ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. P8Z77-M PRO (LGA1155) 31 °C
Storage
    232GB Samsung SSD 840 EVO 250GB (SSD)   27 °C
    3726GB Seagate Expansion Desk USB Device (USB (SATA))   47 °C
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable swapfile.sys on Windows 8?](http://superuser.com/questions/512141/how-to-disable-swapfile-sys-on-windows-8)

Comment: @Ramhound how is limiting its size the same as disabling it?

Comment: magicandre1981's answer explains what to do.

Comment: IMO, you're being a little paranoid/unrealistic about your SSD's life expectancy.

Comment: Related: [What is the purpose of “C:\swapfile.sys” in Windows 8?](http://superuser.com/questions/483302/what-is-the-purpose-of-c-swapfile-sys-in-windows-8)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 source? my 100 tb source is https://www.google.com/search?q=ssd+endurance+experiment https://www.google.com/search?q=The+Samsung+840+Series+started+reporting+reallocated+sectors+after+just+100TB