# High hard drive usage where there shouldn't be

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, hard-drive, memory

Not a problem per-se, more of a question as to why this could possibly be happening.

When I wake up my computer after awhile of being in sleep mode (>1 hr i'd say), it takes quite awhile to become usable, the bottleneck being the HDD, which spikes to max for about 2 mins, and it is quite slow during this time. This is not particularly a problem, as it arises from me keeping way to many things open, usually running at about 90% ram usage, and more on the page file.

Now here's the weird part. See the drive config below to make sure you understand what's going on. During this time, not only is Disk 1 at 100% (which i would expect, since it is running the OS that is waking up), but Disk 0 is also pegged at 100% for the same time period, sometimes longer even! Why would this be happening when it doesn't contain any OS files in use? While some of the documents I have open are saved on that drive, it is not a significant number, and shouldn't account for more than ~30 MB.

Resource monitor tells an interesting story. Pagefile.sys seems to be located on drive G: (which is the windows 7 partition on Disk 0). This, under the process name "System" seems to be what's taking most of the disk time on wake. However, C:\swapfile.sys takes a significant portion as well.

So I suppose my question has morphed into this: What is the difference between pagefile and swapfile, and why is one of them located on a disk that my OS is not.

System Info:

Laptop (HP dv7t-7000)
Windows 10
8 GB of ram
core i7-3610QM
2 HDDs:

-Disk 0: Originally came with the computer (1 TB) contains an old Win7 installation and recovery partitions for it. I use it often to save files to

-Disk 1: (360 GB) I'm running windows 10 off of a 75 GB partition on it. It also includes a corrupted vista install, the recovery partition of a different computer, and a bunch of random linux distros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `C:\swapfile.sys` is [pagefile for the new store apps](https://superuser.com/a/483308/174557). So after resume, Windows reads the memory from the file so that the new apps can resume working. This file is fixed to be in C:. The normal [pagefile can be moved and configured](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=faq-Windows-10&faq=52) in control panel like in all other Windows versions before.

To fix your slowness, install Windows on a SSD.

Comment: yeah, slowness isn't the problem. I've accepted that. Was more curious as to why the secondary HDD was working so hard. Interesting thing about this, is that I have not moved the pagefile. Does that mean that windows 10 somehow searched for and found the pagefile on another partition to use? What would make it do that, and is it still even using the pagefile on C:\ ?

Comment: what is your current pagefile setting? is it configured to use the pagefile.sys from the other drive?

Comment: everything is currently greyed out and set to let windows "automatically manage pagefile sizing for all drives". I have not touched anything since I installed the OS, so this is and has always been the default setting.

Comment: maybe Windows puts the pagefile to the other drive, because it is larger (more free space). look in registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management which value is set for pagefile

Comment: interesting... ExistingPageFiles value is "\??\G:\pagefile.sys" and PagingFiles is "?:\pagefile.sys". That would make sense cause the G partition is huge and my C: partition has been running low on space for awhile. Was unaware windows had the power to put the pagefile elsewhere. Cool! I would think that would cause problems if i took out my Disk 0 HDD though... Unless windows then defaults back to a pagefile on C which i see no entry in the registry for. I suppose that's what the "?" could be

Comment: windows has this power since win95. only the new swapfile.sys and the hibernation file seem to be fixed to be in C:\